# chrome devtools に追加した日本語のパネル名が文字化けする

Tags: chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

[Chromeデベロッパーツールに独自機能を追加する6つのステップ](https://tech.plaid.co.jp/extending_chrome_devtools/)

上記サイトを参考にステップ２でパネルを追加したところで
パネル名を日本語に変更すると文字化けしてしまいます

ソースコードは utf-8 なんですが文字コードは何にすればいいんでしょうか

**ソースコード:**

```
chrome.devtools.panels.create(
  "テスト",
  "", // icon画像を指定できる
  "./panel.html",
  (panel) => {} // callback
);
```

**表示結果:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

devtools.htmlにutf-8指定が抜けているようです

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="./devtools.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: うまくいきました！　JS内で文字コード変換しようとしたんですがHTML側に指定すればよかったんですね